# Select attributes from a layer using Python dictionary keys

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I made a script to find duplicates of cables in a layer and I recorded the REFERENCES of these duplicates in a dictionary.
Now I want to do a SELECT By Attribute with ArcPy to get the duplicates from the main layer and create a new one. I need it to do a processing on the original layer and on the duplicates layer.
Do you have any idea how to do a selection by attribute using dictionary keys? I tried with this code but I get an error that says the query is invalid.

Here is my code:

```
couche_bpe = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_bpe)
couche_cable = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_caftth)
couche_pbo = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_pbo)


champ_a_verfier = ["REFERENCE"]  
values={}
values["Ref_Nulle"]=0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(couche_cable, champ_a_verfier) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] in [None,""]:
            values["Ref_Nulle"]+=1
        else:
            if r[0] not in values:
                values[r[0]]=1
            else:
                values[r[0]]+=1 
del rows

dictDoublons = {}
dictPasDoublons = {}
cable_cda = 'CDA'
count = 0
for item in values:
    if values[item] > 1 :
        if not item.startswith("CDA"):
            dictDoublons[item] = 'Doublons'
            count+=1
            arcpy.AddWarning('Il y a {} cables en doublons  a Verifier / Corriger.'.format(count))
    else:   
        dictPasDoublons[item] = 'PasDoublons'




#Recuperer les cables les plus proches des doublons

for key in dictDoublons:
    selec_cable_doublons = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(couche_cable, "NEW_SELECTION", "[REFERENCE] =  'dictDoublons[key]'")
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetCount_management(cableDoublons))
```

I tried to build the query, it runs fine, but the selection is not done. I know I have 5 duplicates, logically I must have around 10 or a little more if there are triplicates.
here is what I wrote as a code

```
liste_de_doublons = []
for key in dictDoublons:
    liste_de_doublons.append(key)

tuple_doublons = tuple(liste_de_doublons)

for i in tuple_liste:
    resultat_selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(cable_feauture, "NEW_SELECTION", "[REFERENCE] = 'i'")

resultat_selection_feature = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(resultat_selection)
arcpy.GetCount_management(resultat_selection_f)
```

Comment: This isn't how this is usually structured. While the `IN` SQL operator can handle a few features (the number may be limited by engine), it's not the most efficient when working with arbitrarily large sets of features. In any case, you actually have to structure the SQL statement to be valid. While Python's `str.join()` can be useful, the type of the keys requires cleverness in the formatting.

Comment: I tried to build the query, it runs fine, but the selection is not done. I know I have 5 duplicates, logically I must have around 10 or a little more if there are triplicates.

Comment: Sure, since your SQL is not valid. It's not clear from the problem statement, but if your "reference" field (which is in an Access table?) is string, then you need `"[REFERENCE] in ('{:s}')".format("','".join(liste_de_doublons)))` (if integer, then you need to stringify the ints -- `"[REFERENCE] in ({:s})".format(",".join([str(i) for i in liste_de_doublons])))`)

Comment: And this new ArcPy won't work unless you change the "NEW_SELECTION" to "ADD_TO_SELECTION" after the initial select.

Comment: thanks for your help, I just modified my code and it worked. I am new to Arcpy as an apprentice in a company and your comments help me a lot.